# Unable to start the peer in hyperledger fabric, first network sample using custom cryptographic material

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the below link to run the first network sample using the custom crypto graphic material.

[First network sample using custom crypto grapic material](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-build-blockchain-network-with-custom-cryptographic-material-from-your-certificate-authority/index.html)

As explained in the link i have generated all the certificates from the CA and placed the content in the required folders
I generated all the channel artifacts as well.
now when i run the below command for starting the containers i get errors

```
CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

Except the CLI container none of the other containers are coming up

**Error in Orderer**

```
2017-11-10 07:11:47.211 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> WARN 001 Failed reading file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts/signer.crt: no pem content for file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts/signer.crt
```

**Error in all peers**

```
2017-11-10 07:11:47.134 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

**Content of signer.crt for orderer issue**

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

**signer.key file content**

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BggqhkjOPQMBBw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEILa+xgvh9fAIkymEX4ohTlCIMxcZ6jO5KQxD9BZ7LpuWoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEUNJCkwIwfj35tqkz4+QMkcPElPAjuN9UXZ5hhcHy0VGBfqelLJJT
VREG7+rhkSji5j1R3d22OPlloX9ZpZiR6g==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Docker compose base yaml file** [docker-compose-base.yaml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UjJUCqOKgbvEjPbsPtgr41wVlJm9jjYX)

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following header and footer lines of a PEM file must be on a line by themselves, so you need to add newline characters appropriately:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You should also verify that the certificate format is valid by using openssl to display the certificate as follows:

```
openssl x509 -in <filename> -text -noout
```

Comment: Thanks smith i corrected the cert and now i am not getting the 'no pem content issue' but  getting the **KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo** in all the peers and orderer node.

Answer (score 1):

The error for all the peers is caused by the format of your private key.  The Fabric components do not support private keys which include the EC Params.  So you can either delete the

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BggqhkjOPQMBBw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
```

stanza from your signer.key files or regenerate them using

> openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out signer.key